# Is it possible to tell whether a Mac address is an emulator?

Tags: macos

I am planning to write an application that is strictly only compatible with Mac OS. I want it to be robust against Mac emulators, it is very important that only a Mac computer can use it.

I know that Mac computers each have their own unique mac address.

Is it possible to distinguish between a real Macintosh computer and a macintosh emulator like Virtualbox for example? If so can this somehow be figured out with the mac address?

I am open to any framework which can achieve this

Comment: An emulated network card can have any MAC address at all, it's a simple setting on all hypervisors.

Comment: Computers made by Apple and MAC addresses are only similar in the name, they have no connection.

Comment: So there's no way for a program written in say C++ to distinguish between a mac and a mac emulator?